# How to set width and height of rect element based on svg width

Tags: javascript, svg

Hello guys i am making some rect element on a image there is initial width=1100 and height=711 of image i am setting width, height, x and y coordinates according to initial width and height, i am also getting width and height of image from user when user enter width and height with 2:1 aspect ratio rect element width, height, x and y adjusting correctly like image width 600 and height 300 but when user enter width 600 and height 200 the calculations becomes wrong, Please tell me the solution how i achieve this, I am inserting rect in room 14A

```js
const svg = document.querySelector('svg')
const image = document.querySelector('image')
const rect1 = document.querySelector('#id1')

const btn = document.querySelector('button')

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
const width = prompt('enter width')
const height = prompt('enter height')
  const initialWidth = svg.width.baseVal.value
  const initialHeight = svg.height.baseVal.value
  console.log(initialWidth)
  console.log(initialHeight)
  svg.setAttribute('width', width)
  svg.setAttribute('height', height)
  image.setAttribute('width', width)
  image.setAttribute('height', height)
  const scaleFactorX = width / initialWidth;
  const scaleFactorY = height / initialHeight
  console.log(scaleFactorX, scaleFactorY)
  rect1.setAttribute('width', rect1.getAttribute('width') * scaleFactorX);
  rect1.setAttribute('height', rect1.getAttribute('height') * scaleFactorY);
  rect1.setAttribute('x', rect1.getAttribute('x') * scaleFactorX);
  rect1.setAttribute('y', rect1.getAttribute('y') * scaleFactorY);
  console.log(rect1.getAttribute('x') / scaleFactorX)
})
```

```html
<button>resize</button>
<svg width="1100" height="711" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <image href="https://www.pvmchurch.org/uploads/3/3/9/1/3391710/7320601_orig.png" width="1100" height="711" />
  <rect id="id1" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0.4)" width="70" height="98" x="350" y="145" />
  
</svg>
```

Comment: Try only getting the width from the user and setting the height to `width * initialHeight / initialWidth`. it works unless you really want to get the height from the user as well